# Android Navigation Drawer Set Title

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

I want to change the title of my Navigation Drawer when a user clicks on the particular fragment of the navigation drawer. I'm new to the world of Android Programming. So please kindly help Below is my code

Main Activity Code

```
    package com.androidbelieve.HIT_APP;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    NavigationView mNavigationView;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /**
         *Setup the DrawerLayout and NavigationView
         */

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.shitstuff) ;




        /**
         * Lets inflate the very first fragment
         * Here , we are inflating the TabFragment as the first Fragment
         */

        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        // mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new HomeFragment()).commit();


        /**
         * Setup click events on the Navigation View Items.
         */

        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();




              if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_home) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new HomeFragment()).commit();

                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_dept) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new DeptFragment()).commit();

                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_facility) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new FacilityFragment()).commit();

                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_placement) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new PlacementFragment()).commit();

                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_gallery) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new GalleryFragment()).commit();

                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_developer) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new DeveloperFragment()).commit();

                }



                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_near) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new NearFragment()).commit();

                }


                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_notify) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new NotifyFragment()).commit();

                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_vtu) {
                    FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();
                }


                return false;

            }



        });

        /**
         * Setup Drawer Toggle of the Toolbar
         */

        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, toolbar,R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    }
}
```

I think something needs to be done here itself when a person selects any of the drawer items.

Any other piece of code required let me know

Comment: want to change navigation drawer title or ActionBar/ToolBar Title?

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm

Comment: I working on my school project can u please help me!!! How can i mssg you and ask doubts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move variable of `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);` above just after `setContentView` in `onCreate` method of your activity & make it `final`.

when user select navigation drawer set title of `ToolBar` in `onNavigationItemSelected` like below.

```
if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_home) {
   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
   fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new HomeFragment()).commit();
   toolbar.setTitle("Your Fragment Name");
   }
```

---

to set ICON you can use

```
toolbar.setLogo(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.cheese_1));
```

Comment: @sunny: check Edited answer and you can import sample code of support library from android SDK. check path in your android SDK AndroidSDK\extras\android\support\samples many other sample is here AndroidSDK\samples\android-23 all are sample import in Android studio run it. its help you

Comment: how to make gallery in grid view, like the images will be shown in grid view and when u click on it, it will be displayed with some text in it.

Comment: Thanks for that, but when i click on the picture it doesn't protrude. The app crashs instead

Comment: check path in your android SDK AndroidSDK\extras\android\support\samples many other sample is here AndroidSDK\samples\android-23 all are sample import in Android studio run it. all type of sample available here please take look in SDK sample